# Custom attributes in breeze metadata

Tags: breeze

I have some EF classes with properties that contain the `DisplayName` attribute. What would be the correct (if any) way to (dynamically) add this attribute in the breeze metadata so when I call `manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(my_type)` I can read it (like I can do with `MaxLength`? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a method to reflect on your EF classes and extract the display name into the breeze 'Custom Metadata' json structure ( probably using JSON.NET to write the json on the server).  You would then send this 'customMetadata' down to the client and call *MetadataStore.importMetadata* with it like this:

```
 myEntityManager.metadataStore.importMetadata(customMetadata, true);
```

See the sections on [Custom Metadata](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-metadata) and [Metadata by Hand](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand)

Comment: Perfect, the importMetadata is exactly what I needed. Thanks!